# How can one pipe the audio waveform image out of ffmpeg into an image display command/application?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, pipe

These two commands, when used in succession, produce a .png file of the inputted audio waveform.

```
ffmpeg -i audioFile.mp3 -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=640x120" -frames:v 1 imageFile.png
qlmanage -p imageFile.png
```

But I have not succeeded in piping the image from the first to the second.  Simply using "|" between them did not work.

```
ffmpeg -i audioFile.mp3 -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=640x120" -frames:v 1 |
qlmanage -p
```

Error:

```
Filter showwavespic has an unconnected output
```

Sounds pretty fundamental!

Please, how can what I am trying to do be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make FFmpeg to output its output to pipe, you need to instruct it explicitly like this:

```
ffmpeg -i audioFile.mp3 -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=640x120" \
       -frames:v 1 -c:v png -f image2pipe -
```

Disclaimer: I do not know if `qlmanage` can accept the piped image.

Comment: Thank you, and I tried that just now.  I had tried something like that, following some websearch, but (like then) I got a "pipe broken" error, maybe reflecting the possible limitation you warned of.  At least I know I'm on the right kind of path, and can look for an alternative way to display.  (Insufficient reputation to upvote - I tried - sorry)

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175977/preview-image-from-pipe)? (again, no mac user myself, just a random search result.)  BTW, you should be able to mark an answer as "Accepted Answer" (or something similar) by click on the checkmark under the voting ui.

Comment: Looks like qlmanage (macOS's QuickLook) indeed cannot accept piped images.  Just now I tried an alternative display method, in an alternative Terminal app called iTerm, via a script posted elsewhere, called imgcat.  That approach worked - code:
ffmpeg -i  audioFile.mp3  -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=640x120" -frames:v 1 -c:v png -f image2pipe -  | imgcat'
I'm not sure if I'm allowed to link to that script - in an external article.  Websearching on "imgcat" revealed something of that name on Github.  I will try that too.

Comment: Thanks kesh, and now I have indeed accepted your answer.

Comment: Thanks for that other link also kesh.  I will try out those other ways too.